# Unable to render a config file to be added to the container

Tags: nomad

Here's the code below trying to get the file from a git repository but it'll be helpful if e can just get it from the server itself. I sthere's another method to resolve this, simple like a replacement for docker's COPY or ADD.

```
job "test-job" {
  datacenters = ["test-dc"]

  group "test-group" {
    count = 2
    constraint {
        operator = "distinct_hosts"
        value = "true"
      }
    task "test-task" {
      driver = "docker"
      env {
        test_var = "test-value"
      }
      artifact {
        source      = "git::git@<>"
        destination = "local/repo"
        options {
          ssh-key = "<>"
        }
      }
      config {
        image = "test-image"
        hostname = "test-name"
        args = [ "--config", "/etc/test-file.yaml"]
        logging {
          config {
            max-file = 3
            max-size = "20m"
          }
        }
        volumes = ["local/repo/test-file.yaml:/etc/test-file.yaml"]
      }
      resources {
        cpu    = 500
        memory = 256
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `from a git repository but it'll be helpful if e can just get it from the server itself` But git repository is the server itself. I do not understand the question.